# How to get a list via POST in Restangular?

Tags: json, angularjs, rest, post, restangular

Consider a REST URL like /api/users/findByCriteria which receives POSTed JSON that contains details of the criteria, and outputs a list of Users.

How would one call this with Restangular so that its results are similar to Restangulars getList()?

Restangular.all('users').post("findByCriteria", crit)... might work, but I don't know how to have Restangular recognize that the result will be a list of Users

Restangular.all('users').getListFromPOST("findByCriteria", crit)... would be nice to be able to do, but it doesn't exist.

Doing a GET instead of a POST isn't an option, because the criteria is complex.

Comment: You might find it to be much easier to user `$resource` or even `$http` for this. Restangular can be customized to an extent, but it is really meant for use with RESTful services that behave within the confines of something more typical than what you're looking to do. Perhaps you can use a "lower level" service for this method and Restangular for everything else?

Comment: Marc, After it gets a list of users, I want to be able to make a call like: users[0].getList('blogEntries').  I hope restangular has a solution since it is pretty flexible.   Also, doing an addRestangularMethod to a collection won't work since it's method signature is (name, operation, path, params, headers, elementToPost) with no way to pass in what kind of response is expected from the method eg "entity" or "collection".

Comment: I have only used Restangular for a more typical API, where I carefully designed it to be as close to any commonly agreed upon criteria for REST as possible. But I did look over the docs after reading your question and nothing stuck out to me either that would seem to work for you. That's why I suggested using `$resource` or even `$http`. Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks Marc.  I've been searching and reading the documentation-- I have a possible solution with a method I found "restangularizeCollection".  I am still considering switching to GET, but that creates a different set of problems. Another solution is to do a POST to store the criteria, and then a GET, but it bothers me to have to do 2 requests.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

I experience same problem and I workaround it with `plain` function, which return a plain array of objects. but it will remove all Restangular helper functions. So, you cant use it.

Code snippet:

```
Restangular.one('client').post('list',JSON.stringify({
                offset: offset,
                length: length
            })).then(
            function(data) {
                $scope.clients = data.plain();
            },
            function(data) {
              //error handling
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a POST to return a properly restangularized collection by setting a custom handler for `OnElemRestangularized` in a config block. This handler is called after the object has been Restangularized. `isCollection` is passed in to show if the obect was treated as a collection or single element. In the code below, if the object is an array, but was not treated as collection, it is restangularized again, as a collection. This adds all the restangular handlers to each element in the array.

```
   let onElemR = (changedElem, isCollection, route, Restangular: restangular.IService) => {
  if (Array.isArray(changedElem) && !isCollection ) {
    return Restangular.restangularizeCollection(null, changedElem, changedElem.route);
  }
  return changedElem;
};
RestangularProvider.setOnElemRestangularized(onElemR);
```